# Middleware not invoked for synchronous requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, sentry

I try to log unhandled exceptions to sentry using SentryDotNet.AspNetCore.

My startup.cs has

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        var dsn = "[dsn]";


        services.AddSentryDotNet(
            new SentryClient(
                dsn,
                new SentryEventDefaults(
                    environment: "test",
                    release: typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3),
                    logger: "coremvcapp")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSentryDotNet(new SentryDotNetOptions { CaptureRequestBody = true });
 //app.Run(async context => { await DoSomethingAsync(context); });
    }
```

There is a sample call to invoke the middleware which logs successfully to sentry.

```
private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("error"))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Boom");
    }
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("some stuff");
}
```

The problem is that if an exception is thrown in a controller action the middleware is not invoked.

```
    public IActionResult LogError()
    {
        throw new Exception("mvc error");
    }
```

I set a breakpoint to the Invoke method of the middleware and it is not hit when the exception in the action is thrown.

The middleware has this Invoke method

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e) when (_client != null)
        {
            // log stuff

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I see that it gets initialized when the application starts

```
public SentryDotNetMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ISentryClient client, SentryDotNetOptions options)
{
    _next = next;
    _client = client;
    _options = options;

}
```

Is there something missing so that the invoke method of the middleware gets called for the unhandled excetion in the action?

**Edit**

For me the implementation as provided by sentry Sentry.AspNetCore worked out of the box. There were other little glitches with all the other packages I tried.

Comment: Worth noting Sentry has an official support to ASP.NET Core: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/aspnetcore/ (disclaimer: I work at Sentry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order you add middleware is important as they are invoked in the order they were added to the pipeline.

Loggers and error handlers should be added very early to the pipeline.

> Make sure you `UseSentryDotNet()` after any middleware that intercepts exceptions. Otherwise, the `SentryDotNet` middleware will not see the exception. E.g. the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` should be used before `app.UseSentryDotNet()`

Reference [GitHub : SentryDotNet](https://github.com/thedmi/SentryDotNet#startup)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    // Make sure middleware that catches exceptions without 
    // rethrowing them is added *before* SentryDotNet
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    //Add sentry
    app.UseSentryDotNet(new SentryDotNetOptions { CaptureRequestBody = true });

    // Other middleware, e.g. app.UseMvc()

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The reason your example worked is because you added it after having added the sentry middleware.

In the other calls the errors are occurring before it reaches the sentry middleware so they are not going to be caught.

Reference [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Reference [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I was all the time checking that I realy add the midleware  after app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() not realizing that I should also be before other middleware. This is so obvious now.